# How to change the default settings of Camera on MediaCapture Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

I have an app which can capture image (just demo app) but I do not know how to change the Camera mode of this and how to turn on/off/auto of FlashMode, or how to make a camera focuses (I do not know to to present it, sorry) before taking a photo? I tried many examples but they are about Silverlight platform or Universal Windows App when I am developing on Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime.

Can you help me please!

P/s: I used MediaCapture and CaptureElement to take the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links that could help you on your way.

Silverlight:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/AdvancedCamera-ba47da27

WinRT:
http://wpcsharp.blogspot.nl/p/how-to-use-camera-in-wp-81-app.html
http://www.slideshare.net/WindowsPhoneRocks/17-camera-media-and-audio-in-windows-phone-81 (best)

Flashlight WinRT:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn279077

Comment: Bro, It is for Silverlight :'(

Comment: The example is for the WinRT & Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: They noted that but only Silverlight project

Comment: I see what you mean, will report that to MSFT.

Comment: @iamatsundere181 I've added some links from my own library. The slideshare has more information about focus, but I can't find the real WinRT example any more. Hope these help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for this, my boss will avoid to kill me :D